# How can i update a certain widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I want to update the position of a label, so I use .update() method, after I replace it with .place() method. The problem is that all my widgets, that are on my window, get updated and I do not want this, because the program is working harder, and I see lag while "moving" my label. What can I do?

```
...
def update_label:
     l.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.1+0.2)
     l.update()#here the program is updating every widget

l=tk.Label(root)
l.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.1)

b=Button(root,command(update_label()))
b.pack()
...
```

In fact, I want to replace more than one label in update_label function, but I wanted to make the example easier to understand.

Comment: How should I write that?(Can you write the whole expression?)

Comment: Gheorghe: Sorry, my earlier comment about using the `config()` method didn't apply — it's for updating a widget's options, like color, size, etc, _not_ its position. See the answer I posted on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.update()` method, but there are a few things wrong with your code.

First off, you use the `tk` attribute with the label, but not with the button. Try to be consistent.

I reworked your code and made it cleaner. It now works:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
x = 0.2
y = 0.1

l = tk.Label(root, text = "label")
l.place(relx = x, rely = y)
def update_label():
    global x, y
    y += 0.2
    l.place(relx = x, rely = y)
    l.update()#here the program is updating every widget


b = tk.Button(root,text = "update", command = update_label)
b.pack()
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Writing `l.update()` won't update or move any other widgets. If you wish to move/update all widgets, then you **must** put them in the `update_label()` function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't look like it will update only the specific label. I do not want to update all the others widgets(frames, buttons, labes, etc) that I have in my program. If I write l.update() is same like if I write root.update() and I do not want this.

Comment: _If I write l.update() is same like if I write root.update() and I do not want this_. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. Do you have an ideea if the fact that I am having too many widgets placed on my window could cause that lag movement? I mean, I tried to comment a part of my code where I create and place these multiple widgets(buttons, labels, frames, etc...) and let only the labels that I want to move, and I noticed that the movemet of the these labels is more faster and smoother.

Comment: @GheorgheGh If it is lagging, that means there are too many widgets on your window. Normally to fix this you could convert the file to an exe file, and then it will run a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

To update the position of a single widget, you can use the [`place_forget()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) method to temporarily remove it and then call its `place()` method (again) with new values to reposition it. Since it appears you want to update the position based on the where the widget currently is, information about the widget's current position is retrieved from it first using the `place_info()` widget method.

Here's a runnable example based on the code in your question that illustrates what I'm suggesting:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")


def update_label(lbl):
    info = lbl.place_info()  # Get dictionary of widget's current place options.

    cur_relx = float(info['relx'])  # Get current value of relative x.
    cur_rely = float(info['rely'])  # Get current value of relative y.

    lbl_1.place_forget()  # Remove widget from current manager.
    lbl_1.place(relx=cur_relx, rely=cur_rely+0.2)  # Add it back with updated y position.


lbl_1 = tk.Label(root, text='Label 1')
lbl_1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1)

lbl_2 = tk.Label(root, text='Label 2')
lbl_2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)

btn_1 = tk.Button(root, text='Update', command=lambda lbl=lbl_1: update_label(lbl))
btn_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```