# Adding and updating new widget in tkinter in runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, evaluation

I am trying to build a GUI creator using Python and Tkinter, but ran into a problem.

My problem is **How to add\update widgets in runtime?**

for example:

- I have created the main window.
- In that main window, I have created a frame name `w_frame` which contains a bunch of widget.
- Based on my input in the Text or Entry widget beside the `w_frame`, I want to update a particular widget.
- Lets say `w_frame` contains a Entry widget, radio button, button and label all available with the basic or main attributes need to display it.
- Now I want to change the background color of label.
- In short I want to write the code `label_name.property_name=value` or for example `a_label.bg=red` in the text widget and as soon as I press apply button, the widget should change.

I have searched on web, but not able to find the required solution. Also tried using [How can i update a certain widget in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783777/how-can-i-update-a-certain-widget-in-tkinter), but that does not work depending on my input.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
w_frame=Frame()
w_frame.pack()
def update_Frame():
    a=u_text_wid.get("1.0",END)
    b.config(a)
    root.update()
def add_wid_in_frame():
    global a,b
    a=Button(w_frame,text='heelo')
    a.pack()
    b=Label(w_frame,text='heelo')
    b.pack()
u_text_wid=Text()
u_text_wid.pack()
button1=Button(text="add",command=add_wid_in_frame)
button1.pack()
button1=Button(text="update",command=update_Frame)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

this results me in an error

> unknown option "-bg="red"

Note:
I want to update the widget based on the property value provided by the user, so it wont be hard-code into the script.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and the full error traceback as you said *"ran into a problem"*.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do `label_name.config(bg="red")`? Can you show us an example that doesn't work? Calling `config` on a widget "at runtime" is a very common thing to do.

Comment: @acw1668 , I have added an example, please let me know if there are anyother problems.

Comment: @BryanOakley , I think you didnt get me, i dont want to hard code `label_name.config(bg="red")` into the script. According the input provided by the user in the text box, the widget would change its property.

Comment: You need to pass keyword options instead of a string to `.config()`.

Comment: @acw1668 , how do i do it?

Comment: everything i pass on text widget would be treated as an string only, how would i change it to a keyword?

Comment: What do you expect the user to type into the `Text` widget? Are you expecting them to enter python code?

Comment: @BryanOakley , Yes thats what i am expecting.

Comment: Then this really isn't about tkinter, you asking how to evaluate python code given to you by the user. The fact that the code comes from a tkinter widget or that the code might contain references to a tkinter widgets seems largely irrelevant.

Comment: But the code would be of tkinter it self to be evaluated.

Comment: That’s irrelevant. The problem is the same no matter what type of objects you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: @BryanOakley , what if i need to change the property of the a widget, let's say background of a lable using the entry widget, that would be relevant right, like writing label_name.bg="red"?

Comment: Not executing the whole code, but changing the property according to the input.

Comment: You said you wanted the user to input _code_, so they can input code to change the background of a widget, change a row in a database, or do anything else you can do in code. That's why tkinter is irrelevant if your question is asking how to execute any random bit of code the user inputs.

Comment: @BryanOakley, i just wanted to change the property of widget, which i thought would require executing the code itself, but the both below answer works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because every thing you retrieve from `Text` widget is a string and you cannot directly pass an string to `.config` method, you need a keyword and then you can assign value which can be string.

According to your question and the comments on the question, what i have figured out is:

- You want to run `lable.config(bg='red')` from the `Text` widget.
- You want to change the property of specific widget.

Here's what you can do:

1. To run Tkinter code form `Text` widget, you can use:

- `getattr` method
- `eval` method

4. Just to change property of widget:

```
def update_Frame():
    global bcd
    a = u_text_wid.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    b=a.split(",")
    c=[tuple(i.split("=")) if "=" in i else i for i in b]
    d=dict(i for i in c)
    for key,value in d.items():
        bcd[key]=value
```

- We can use string to change property only in this format `widget_name[key]=value`.

Some Useful Links:

- [Eval()](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-eval-built-in-function-601f87db191#:%7E:text=What%20is%20eval%20()%20in,the%20result%20as%20an%20integer.)
- [Getattr()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr)

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert a JSON string to dictionary and use the dictionary in `.config()`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
...
def update_Frame():
    a = u_text_wid.get("1.0", "end-1c") # don't include ending newline
    cnf = literal_eval(a) # convert JSON string to dictionary
    b.config(cnf)
```

Example input of the JSON string:

```
{"fg":"yellow", "bg":"red"}
```

Note that you can also use `json` module to convert the JSON string as well.

Comment: but the output from the text widget wont be in json format, so why to convert

Comment: My suggestion requires JSON format.

Comment: Can you provide me the advantage of using json as i have figured out a way to change the property witb same logic of your code but without json.

Comment: I think using JSON is simple and straight forward.  But if you find your way, just use it.